# JUnit5 (aggregator) provides old dependencies

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

I am using `JUnit5 aggregator`:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
     <version>5.5.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I show my dependency tree, I see old versions of api:

```
[INFO] \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.3.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.3.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.3.2:test
[INFO]    \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.3.2:test
[INFO]       \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.3.2:test
```

But why? Why is junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.1 providing me old versions (5.3.2) of junit-jupiter-api? How can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps there is a a `dependencyManagent` section in your (parent) pom hinting to specific versions?

Comment: @Elias, I using spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE. He is not contains junit5 dependencies